# Is this an official Lego minifigure?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I have a spiderman figure, that does fit to Lego bricks and who's hands are the same as a Lego Minifigure, but I can't find out if it is an official (albeit somewhat older) Lego product.  Any ideas?

[image: Here it is next to an Indiana Jones official minifig to show scale.]

[image: And from the back]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like [Spider-Man (Junior-fig)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=4j004). Although it is not so easy to confirm if your item is LEGO or clone-branded minifigure. You could look inside the legs if there are any LEGO logos.

[image]